# What does a popup button cell return to the table view implementation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a popup button cell in my table. I'm receiving values the user selects using the tableview implementation. ie:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)returnObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
   // Stuff
}
```

I've figured out how to get values from checkboxes. IE:

```
[returnObject boolValue]
```

Also from slider cells

```
[returnObject intValue]
```

But what's returned from popUp cells? Everything I try to pull from the object errors out. I'm populating the popup with an array of strings...

Comment: FYI: `NSLog(@"Class is %@", [[returnObject class] description]);`

Comment: OOOOH! I totally didn't know you could do that!

I'm new to ObjC. Thank you. That totally put me down the right path. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: Glad to help :-) If you've found your answer, please post and accept it, to reduce the number of unanswered questions on SO.

Comment: Or you can just use `[returnObject className]`.

Comment: SO won't let me self answer for at least 8 hours because I'm a newer user.

The answer is that it returns a NSNumber (actually a private subclass of NSNumber). Popup buttons can get their values from [returnObject stringValue]

This is confusing, because it's actually returning a number as a string in my case...

Comment: @MatthewJones: What are you putting into the pop-up button cells?

Comment: I've got it bound to an Array... NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil]; - It's spitting back strings "0", "1", and "2". The problem with this is that even when I shove those values in my model it doesn't update in the table. Tried recreating as an array of custom objects with "Name" and "Value" properties. Now it's filling the popup cells with the memory locations of the objects... Still struggling through this. I feel like there's some part of popup cells that I'm just not wrapping my head around yet...

Comment: @MatthewJones: Please be more specific about the binding. Which binding did you bind? What object did you bind it to? What property did you bind to?

Comment: I created a custom class inheriting from NSObject. That class has two properties "name" and "value". I then created three instances of that class, each with it's own name and value. Then I added all three objects into a NSMutable Array. After that I created an array controller with it's content array bound the to NSMutable Array I just created. Finally I bound the pop up cell's content and content values to the array controllers arranged objects. Does that make sense? This would probably be a better fit for an enum since the selections will never change, but I'm not making that work either.

Comment: @MatthewJones: Close. `contentValues` should be bound to `arrangedObjects.name`, assuming you want the names to be displayed as the menu items' titles. This may also solve the problem of what will be the cell's value; if it works as I'd expect, you can put the objects into a dictionary to look them up by name.